# top space issue with CSS relative position

Tags: html, css

Can't get the form to be INSIDE the frame for the life of me when using relative position. In absolute it works, but changes spots depending on window size. 
Help!
Here's the outcome
http://orange-restoration.com/water-damage-24-hour-help/

Comment: Can you post the relevant html/css please? Perhaps create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please refrain from solely posting links to your site when asking a question - include code or even better a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the problem.

Comment: Sorry - and sure! See below

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
<div id="main">
```

to position:relative, then set your

```
<div id="main-form">
```

to position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="main-form">
        <H3>Let us call YOU back </H3>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://form.jotform.com/jsform/92640718225"></script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-form
{
    position: relative;
        top: 300px;
    left: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 30px 30px 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
        z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888888;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#888888:
}
```